# ActiveAdmin and self relation model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm new to ROR.
Installed ActiveAdmin and register deparments model with it

Departments DB table like this:

```
id parent_id name
```

Departments Model:

```
class Departments < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :parent_id

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Departments'

  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

and in active admin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Departments do
  menu :parent => 'Manage'
  index do 
    column :parent_id
    column :name
    default_actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Departments" do
      f.input :parent_id
      f.input :name
    end
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

on the index page its showing id number under Parent column
i've two questions

1. how can i show Parent Name instead of showing parent id
2. when adding new department , how to show the drop-down for Parent
   field having all the department names instead of text field.

When i click on the view links it shows correctly the Parent name instead of Parent ID

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting

```
column :parent
input :parent
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Departments do
  index do
    column :parent
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if that doesn't work, you can be more explicit

```
ActiveAdmin.register Departments do
  index do
    column :parent do |resource|
      resource.name
    end
  end
end
```

for the input menu

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "New" do
    f.input :parent, :as = :select, :collection => Department.all, :member_label => lambda { |i| i.name }
  end
end
```